# Hibernate Error - Already have an associated managed connection

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, transactions

I'm randomly receiving this hibernate error, I can't reproduce it.

Already have an associated managed connection

and the stack trace as follows ...

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/31 18:16:20 | org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/31 18:16:20 |       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:170)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/31 18:16:20 |       at com.xxx.sss.helpers.HibernateUtil.getObjectsByCriteria(HibernateUtil.java:54)
```

My selector method is this:

```
public static ArrayList<?> getObjectsByCriteria(String sqlQuery, List<Object> params, int firstResult, int maxSize)
{
    ArrayList<Object> result = null;
    try
    {
        SessionFactoryHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();
        Query q =  SessionFactoryHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(sqlQuery);

        if(params != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
            {
                q.setParameter(i, params.get(i));
            }
        }
        if(firstResult != -1 && maxSize != -1)
        {
            q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            q.setMaxResults(maxSize);
        }
        q.setReadOnly(true);

        result = (ArrayList<Object>) q.list();

    }
    catch(HibernateException ex)
    {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
        logQueryAndParams(sqlQuery, params);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
        logQueryAndParams(sqlQuery, params);

    }
    finally
    {
        if(!SessionFactoryHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().wasCommitted())
            SessionFactoryHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting this?  I've googled it, but very few responses.  I'm not using Spring just straight up Tomcat/Hibernate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For one thing Hibernate's Session class has two very important, but distinct methods. One is `session.createQuery()`
The createQuery() method executes a HQL (Hibernate Query Language) statement on the database using the Java objects that map to the database tables.

However, looking at your parameter name in the method above, it seems that you are executing an SQL query; not a HQL query. For that reason, the alternative method provided by the Session class must be used:

```
session.createSQLQuery()
```

Therefore, if you are executing an SQL query on the database, not a HQL query, then your code would be as follows:

```
Query q =  SessionFactoryHelper.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
```

Hopefully that will make the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Sorry, they are all HQL queries =)  Just a badly named variable on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you never rollback the transaction in case of error (inside the `catch` blocks). I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem though. Also, the usual way to handle transactions is to do the commit at the end of the `try` block, not in the `finally` block, because you don't want to call `commit` if there is an error. [Here's an example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-transaction-handle-example/).

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you already have a running transaction on your JDBC connection
The problem may be because of the @PersistenceContext annotation that you may be using

Replace 
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)

with 
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
or 
@PersistenceContext